# ASP MVC filling model as List Exception

Tags: asp.net-mvc, list

Im stuck at the follow code:

I have a Model OrderList which contains just the following:

```
public class OrderList : List<Tuple<Bagel, BagelType, int>>
{

}
```

And in my controller I want to make a new OrderList en fill it with a function:

```
public ActionResult OrderReport()
    {
        OrderList lstitems = FillBagelCart2();

        return ViewPdf("Order report", "ReportView",lstitems);        
    }

FillBagelCart2 returns a List<Typle<Bagel, BagelType, int>>
```

The error is:

Error   14 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List>' to 'BestelBagels.Models.OrderList'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

No idea why this doesn't work..

Greets

Already works! I had to make a function which returns an orderlist, filled up with the values like that list.. Can be closed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whilst you can implicitly cast from `OrderList` to `List<Tuple<Bagel,BagelType,int>>` because it inherits from it you cannot cast in the opposite direction because it would be possible for `OrderList` to contain methods and properties that the base list doesn't implement.

You either need change the return type of `FillBagelCart2` to `OrderList` or provide the appropriate constructor to your OrderList class to allow it to take an existing collection.

```
public class OrderList : List<Tuple<Bagel, BagelType, int>>
{
    public OrderList() : base() {}

    public OrderList(IEnumerable<List<Tuple<Bagel,BagelType,int>> items) : base(items) {}
}
```

Then you can do

```
OrderList lstitems = new OrderList(FillBagelCart2());
```